# Update list items from a webpart hosted in another site collection not working with batch update (PnPjs)

Tags: pnpjs

I have recently faced this issue and took many hours of wandering around google to find the correct solution/reason for the issue. So I thought about adding it to stack exchange.

**Issue**

There was issue with batch update of list items in a site collection from a SPFx webpart which is deployed in another site collection. But,
batch updation was working well when the list to be updated is within the site collection where the webpart is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my issue I found it here. https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/1338

**The reason for the issue was PnPjs batches are case sensitive with the URL.**
If your site collection url is this

```
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Project
```

and you creating the batch like this

```
let sourceWeb = Web("https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/project");    
const list = sourceWeb.getList("/sites/Projects/Lists/ProjectPlan");
const batch = sourceWeb.createBatch();
const items = list.items.inBatch(batch);
```

It won't work.
So, hardcoding the URL may cause issue if there is case mismatch.